# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'powerfactory'

Tags: python

I want to run PowerFactory in Python. I add Python path into the Digsilent PowerFactory at first. And when I try to import PowerFactory, it always shows 'no module named powerfactory'. I don't know the reason. I wish someone could help me. Thank you!

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\DIgSILENT\PowerFactory 2021 SP1\Python\3.8')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import powerfactory as pf
app = pf.GetApplication()
if app is None:
    raise Exception('getting Powerfactory application failed')
```

Comment: How did you install PowerFactory? Did the installation give an error?

Comment: Have you closed PowerFactory before running the script?
it is not possible to run the script when an instance of PowerFactory is open.

Comment: I have installed PowerFactory, and I run some simulations in it. There are no errors.

Comment: I close the powerfactory. But it still shows no module named powerfactory

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the version of Python and PowerFactory should keep the same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).